# Dynamically auto refresh datagridview every 3 seconds vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, timer, refresh

In my form I have a datagridview which needs to be **automatically refreshed** every 2 seconds without me having to close the application. I have used the following timer code to try and achieve that. I have placed this code in my form load which is also where my datagridview code is:

```
 Dim timer As New Timer()
 timer.Interval = 2000
 AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf timer_Tick
 timer.Start()

Private Sub timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()

End Sub
```

However, all it does is flicker and *doesn't actually refresh the datagridview*. My datagrid is connected to a Access database and is **not binded**, I did with SQL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To refresh data you have to run the query again not `Refresh`

Comment: Also, is this a `DataGridView` or a `DataGrid` they are different?

Comment: DataGridView, but I need it to do that every 3 seconds automatically but if I run the query again wouldn't it just do that if I did something to the datagridview in the application.

Comment: it will not run a query unless you ask it to do so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DGV.Refresh` tell the the program to redraw the control. You need to rerun the process that gets your data and recall it.

```
Private Sub timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  UpdateDGV()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateDGV()
  'run sql stuff in here
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, it worked! I see what you mean now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just another question, I've used this method to update my combobox, but how can I stop it refreshing when I've selected the combobox.

Comment: You make a class level boolean variable and toggle as needed

Comment: Sorry where would I put that... I have a selectedindexchanged

Comment: You have to consider the logic behind what it is doing, if they select something then toggle to false, then what toggles it back? Consider making this a separate question/post.

Comment: Selectedvalue is databound property, `If cb.SelectedIndex = -1 then updatecombo()`

Comment: Oh, I see. I have tried your way and it's still refreshing it when selected